# How do you abstract out an HTML template literal from a JavaScript file, to a separate file, and import it back?

Tags: javascript, html, import, export, literals

EDIT 1/21/2019:
My HTML template literal is getting too long. How can I abstract it out into a separate file, and import it back into my current file?

```
class HelloWorldController extends Controller {

  index_action(req, res, next) {

    return res.send(
      `
      <html>
        ABSTRACT OUT THIS EXCESSIVELY LONG HTML TEMPLATE LITERAL
      </html>
      `
    );
  }
  ... etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the HTML file as a string, like so:

```
// MyHTML.js 
export const myHTML = `<html>...` // your complete html as a string

// HelloWorldController.js
import MyHTML from './MyHTML' // import your html
```

And you can use it here:

```
 return res.send(MyHTML);
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, but is there any way have the complete html in an **.html** vs. your **.js** suggestion?

Reason for requesting this is the color coding in a text editor like Atom.io. The long string in **.js** would be all green while on the other hand it would be color-coded and organized in an **.html**

Comment: You can take a look at `fs` to load files as text: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_filesystem.asp